# OS collapsed after installing Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 13.4 to 13.10. There was a system hang at the time of installation and I had to force-shutdown by pressing the power key. When I try to login, I see that the total OS has collapsed now. I am not able to open any folder or file.

How should I fix it?

Comment: did you able to login?how did you upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't open files or folders but you can log in? That's what I get from the question.

Try pressing Ctrl+Alt+F2 this should take you into a terminal where you can log in.

From here run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

then

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

And for good measure (not sure if you need it but it can't hurt)

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Hopefully this should solve it.